# Java USB Event Listener to get notified when usb is plugged in

Tags: java, netbeans, usb, event-listener, systemeventlistener

I am writing a software in java, netbeans  and there's a module in which I need to run a code whenever​ a "usb" specifically an "android device" is plugged in or plugged out

So I need to know if there's any java class I can use
Like usb event listener or anything

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/quickstart/index.html) might be an option.